# 空の2次元配列の結合を.concatで意図した結合ができない

Tags: ruby

空の2次元配列`buff`に対して2つの配列の結合を`.concat`で下記のように行いたいです．
例：

```
# 配列[1, 2, 3, 4]と配列[10, 11, 12, 13]を結合
buff[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
buff[1] = [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

しかし，下記のコードでは`buff`のオブジェクトIDが同じが原因なのかどうなのかがわからず，期待した結合ができません．
方法をご教授お願いします．

```
buff = Array.new(2, [])
p buff

buff[0].concat([1, 2, 3, 4])
p buff

buff[1].concat([10, 11, 12, 13])
p buff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因についてはお察しの通りbuff[0]とbuff[1]が同じオブジェクトを指してるからです。
解決法としては

```
buff = Array.new(2){[]}
```

という風に初期値をブロックで渡すこと
もしくは

```
buff[0] += [1, 2, 3, 4]
buff[1] += [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

という風に破壊的でないメソッドで配列を結合すること
いずれかを使うのが典型的なやり方でしょう

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．ご指摘の方法でできました．ありがとうございます．